# Notifications on new questions from Stack Exchange App

Tags: discussion, android-app

I recently downloaded the stack exchange app and it gave me a nice little pop up when somebody responded to my comment. Great!

What I want to know is can I set it to give me notifications on new questions in a specific tag?

Comment: For info, you can get *email* notification of new questions in designated tags by subscribing to a tag; there's also per-tag rss feeds. An app-based notification is an interesting option, though, I agree.

Comment: Could this be tagged as [meta-tag:feature-request]? This would be *really* useful for low volume tags.

Comment: I would definitely appreciate this feature as well